# Jenkins miniOrange SAML 2.0 failed login

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have installed and configured miniorange plugin following exactly this setup: https://plugins.miniorange.com/saml-single-sign-on-sso-into-jenkins-using-google-apps-g-suite-as-idp#1549619168146-1d45d518-daa7. Google Apps are redirecting me to my instance, but when I try to log in, it says:

```
More than one user found with this email address.
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solved it already?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I switched to another plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/saml/

Answer (score 0):

Error itself stating the solution. Same user can be somewhere else in your Jenkins configuration. To be specific, check your "People" and "Jenkins owned database Users", You will get same user in both pools but possibly with different name. So remove one of them or specifically user that you or admin created in Jenkins Own Database and try.

In "People" pool you will get users those are participating or contributing in triggering Jobs(either by Github commit or other mode) and Jenkins captures the UserID. So keep this UserID as your desired user name and set your authorization or permission in "Matrix based authorization".